# Toggling sidebar on swipe

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'd like to use swipeleft/swiperight to toggle my sidebar but apparently using these imports

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

don't work so much. If i put the jquery.min.js before the 2 jquery.mobile the toggle doesnt work.. But if i put it like this the swipeleft/swiperight does not work. I want to call semantic ui's sidebar on swipeleft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some things mixed up.

`jquery.min.js` and `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` may be the same thing, although there might be version differences.  Try eliminating one.

Comment: Glad I could assist.  I've run into this many times, especially when working on various content management systems.

Comment: Oh. Thanks again! I am still a newbie programmer heh. Thank you!